# Can I Use The Stock Honda Pilot Subwoofer On an AF Headunit

Tags: honda, audio, electronics, pilot

I'm thinking about getting the Pioneer AVH-X5800BHS headunit for my 2005 Honda Pilot EX but I want to keep costs as low as possible, so can I use the stock subwoofer by tapping into the Sub+ and Sub- wires with some PosiTap connectors or will I have to buy a separate powered subwoofer. Is there an amplifier built in to the car or does the stock headunit amplify the signal inside the unit? I have heard that the subwoofer is 50W. I tried researching this but I got many mixed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVH-X5800BHS has a 70 watt channel dedicated to a subwoofer.  This is good into 2 ohms, so this should work very well on your Honda Pilot.

[AVH-X5800BHS Specifications](http://www.brandsmartusa.com/pdfs/manuals/20202193.pdf)

Refer to page 54 for wiring information for a subwoofer.  Note that wiring depends on speaker impedance, so in your case you should see if the magnet is labeled, or measure DC resistance with a meter.

If you are unsure about the wiring, you should google or go to Crutchfield to locate a specific harness adapter for your head unit and specific vehicle.  This will not only save a lot of time, it leaves the OEM stock harness intact, in case you ever change again or even change back to stock for resale.

Comment: So, to clarify I can just breakout the RCA jack and connect it up directly to the sub + and - pins with the positap connectors?

Comment: @p7810456  No, not at all.  The RCA jacks are for an external amplifier.  I beleive your new head unit has a amp channel for a subwoofer already.

Comment: Resistance and impedance are different. The reading you get with a meter will not accurately represent the impedance of the speaker when a signal is running through it. It's best to look up the specs if you're concerned, but you will rarely if ever see a speaker impedance below 2 ohms, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 agreed, but OEM specs are hard to find if it's not printed on the magnet.  A DVOM reading will get you close enough to decide how to wire this installation.  I wasn't concerned of going below 2 ohms, the amplifier section has two finals taps depending on whether the subwoofer is 2 ohm or 4 ohm and higher.

Comment: @SteveRacer so on the harness for the radio there will be a sub + and - that I could directly PosiTap onto the car's sub + and -?

Comment: @p7810456  Yes, please look at page 54 in the link.  It shows pins and wire colors for the subwoofer output.

Comment: 1 more question, do you know the wastage of the stock subwoofer and the stock speakers?